# Separate product catalog website and customer registration for two customer type

Tags: magento

I need that my website can handle 2 type of product catalog

1. For General customers (b2c)
2. For Dealers (b2b)

On http://www.domainname.com/ it will show product & categories for General customers (b2c).
On http://www.domainname.com/b2b/ it will show product & categories for Dealers (b2b).

I have created 2 websites,  1 Store for each website,  1 Store view for each store. e.g.

```
Website Name | Store Name | Store View Name  
B2C Website | B2C Store | B2C Store View (b2c)  
Dealer Website | Dealer Store | Dealer Store View (b2b)
```

I am not able to view my dealer website using link like this
http://www.domainname.com/b2b/
It gives me 404. I think it is looking for the CMS Page which doesn't exists.

**What should I do to display the dealer product catalog on this link?**

Also when the user register as dealer using link
http://www.domainname.com/b2b/customer/account/create/
**The customer should autmatically assigned as Dealer customer group. How to do this?**

Answer (score 0):

Set website Url for every website you have in Sustem->Config->General->Web (Base URL for secure/unsecure).
Then configure your .htaccess:
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domainname.com$`
`RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:website_1_code]`
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domainname.com/b2b$`
`RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:website_2_code]`
So magento will startup right website depending of requested url.